# Can a freed-up memory segment be accessible from a process core?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, memory-leaks

Can a freed-up heap memory segment previously allocated with Malloc be accessible from the core, given the address? Given the fact that every free() will not return back the memory to the kernel pool (because of the local memory management).

If yes, how could it be differentiated from the access on a valid (not freed) address?

Basically, I am trying to dump some data structures from the core. And wondering, if I will be dealing with the valid data structures or previously allocated but freed-up

Answer (score 0):

Even trying to access previously freed memory is *undefined behaviour*.

If it was indeed freed, it might for example be reused by your own program, so the address would still be "owned" by it. Accessing it through a freed pointer will however *not* do what you expect (or maybe it will, because undefined behaviour).

So no, you can not simply check if a pointer was freed, you need to get your memory management right yourself. Techniques like [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) will help you with that.

Comment: thanks, but What is RAII ? Also, I vaguely remember some gdb config option to remove memory protection. Somehow, can't figure that out. Undefined how ?

Comment: @joe Added a link explaining RAII. Undefined behaviour means literally anything is allowed to happen: If you dereference a freed pointer, you program might work, call your mom, impregnate your father... You cannot reason over UB because all guarantees are void.